# Change color of "hint"

Tags: android, colors, hint

How can i change the color of "hint" in my code?

Because with a dark background, i can't see the text and the place where i need to write...
Thank you so much for your help !

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Veuillez taper son prénom ici"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

in a `<LinearLayout> android:background="@color/colorBlack"/>`

Comment: add the following   android:textColorHint= "" define your hint textcolor in the enclosed qoutes

Answer (score 0):

In your XML code you can add `android:textColorHint` :

```
<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Veuillez taper son prénom ici"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:textColorHint="#ff0000"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

OR you can change the hint color programmatically :

```
edittext.setHintTextColor(Color.RED);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add id to EditText to identify tag.
.xml file

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/ET_hint"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Veuillez taper son prénom ici"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

.java file

```
EditText et_hint = findViewById(R.id.ET_hint);
et_hint.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:textColorHint="#ff0000"` in your xml or `edittext.setHintTextColor(Color.BLUE);` to set hint color in your Java program grammatically.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using the Material design library. Currently, I am using the version

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'

if you are using the Material design library. Currently, I am using the version

implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha01'

1 - Set color when TextInputLayout is resting.

```
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/your_color_hint</item>
```

2 - Set color when TextInputLayout is floating/focused/tapped.

```
<item name="hintTextColor">@color/your_color_floating_hint</item>
```

3 - Set color of the line under TextInputLayout.

```
<item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/TextViewColor_line</item>
```

4 - Set color of the error under TextInputLayout.

```
<item name="boxStrokeErrorColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
```